# How does "Fides" from the German Bundesdruckerei work?

Tags: privacy, authorization

I'm no security or cryptographic expert, just an interested computer scientist - so this question may be at the wrong place, or contain wrong assumptions. Nevertheless:

[The German Bundesdruckerei here explains](https://www.bundesdruckerei.de/en/Whitepaper-Almighty-Administrator-Self-determined-User) they have found the solution to privacy and data protection: They call their system FIDES, but from the document, I don't understand how it's supposed to work.

- They say the original documents (or other rights, such as entry to a lab) are separate from the FIDES chains. How are the two linked?
- I cannot glean from the paper whether it's a centralized or decentralized (like Bitcoin) system.
- And I did not see an explicit mention of "security" - how to secure the chains against a compromised server or device? How to ensure malicious clients cannot raise their owner's permission?

Apart from the cited whitepaper, I did not find other sources, esp. regarding the security this system really provides. (After many spectacular failures of secure IT in Germany, I think I need independent assurances :-)

So is there enough material out there to really judge this already?